# how to fix java.lang.AssertionErrorSupported FPS ranges cannot be null of CameraX which occurs on Mi A2 android 9

Tags: android, androidx, android-camerax

### Received the following crash on crashlytics from MI A2 device

**Question**

This code works on most of the devices except some devices (eg: Mi A2). What should I do to fix this?

What may be the possible reason to cause this crash with cameraX?

**Stacktrace**

```
 Fatal Exception: java.lang.AssertionErrorSupported FPS ranges cannot be null.
Fatal Exception: java.lang.AssertionError: Supported FPS ranges cannot be null.
at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.LegacyMetadataMapper.mapControlAe(LegacyMetadataMapper.java:411)
at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.LegacyMetadataMapper.mapCharacteristicsFromParameters(LegacyMetadataMapper.java:183)
at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.LegacyMetadataMapper.createCharacteristics(LegacyMetadataMapper.java:153)
at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(CameraManager.java:277)
at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.compat.CameraManagerCompatBaseImpl.getCameraCharacteristics(CameraManagerCompatBaseImpl.java:109)
at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.compat.CameraManagerCompatApi28Impl.getCameraCharacteristics(CameraManagerCompatApi28Impl.java:87)
at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.compat.CameraManagerCompat.getCameraCharacteristicsCompat(CameraManagerCompat.java:171)
at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.SupportedSurfaceCombination.<init>(SupportedSurfaceCombination.java:115)
at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2DeviceSurfaceManager.init(Camera2DeviceSurfaceManager.java:104)
at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2DeviceSurfaceManager.<init>(Camera2DeviceSurfaceManager.java:92)
at androidx.camera.camera2.internal.Camera2DeviceSurfaceManager.<init>(Camera2DeviceSurfaceManager.java:65)
at androidx.camera.camera2.Camera2Config.lambda$defaultConfig$0(Camera2Config.java:52)
at androidx.camera.camera2.-$$Lambda$Camera2Config$kPfcZYYQs2fXKvw1cjC5GhRy6hM.newInstance()
at androidx.camera.core.CameraX.lambda$initAndRetryRecursively$9$CameraX(CameraX.java:592)
at androidx.camera.core.-$$Lambda$CameraX$u-Xx2b6YXY5GXNXRh-mDiDnHdpQ.run(:10)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

I am using camerax_version = "1.0.1"

Comment: Could you share your code? Are you overwriting the default FPS range with Camera2InterOp?

Comment: I got the same crash report from Crashlytics, happened on a Moto G (5) Plus. 
@Xi张熹 At least I'm not overwriting anything. Maybe some devices do not offer any values for this FPS range?

Comment: It seems like a device bug. If you could file a bug here, we can take a look: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192731&template=842428&pli=1